# Cinema site, retrive the movies that actor play in

Tags: php

Hy, im building a cinema site in wp...

For movies - I am using POST - The movies are post there.. 
For actors - I am using post_type : persoane , Taxonomy : lista.

Ex: In post i add the movie, with title....etc..i'm usig custom field
Picture: http://cinema.trancelevel.com/1.jpg

For displayng the actors,regizor... i'm using relationship.
When i introduce the actor in relationship field, i want automate to get the movie in Actor page...

Ex: http://cinema.trancelevel.com/persoane/bruce-willis/

Now the big problem is how can i get the movies in actor page.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to list actors worked in a movie on the Movie Page and Vice Versa,, right ?

Then you should consider using plugin called [post-to-post](http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts) to connect your Movies posts and Actors posts.

Recently I came across an article by one of the WP developers itself, He developed a similar kind of site and shared the steps and tricks he used. [Article by Mark](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/how-i-built-have-baby-need-stuff/)

Comment: +1 for Scribu's plugin, the examples in the documentation are exactly "Movies" and "Actors"!

Comment: Hy the problem was resolved...

Comment: Hey, If this answer resolved your problem then consider approving it so it'll help those who are looking for answer.